# I want to copy a file from host to guest while spinning a vm .. any pointers?

Tags: config, openstack

Since network is not setup on my cluster ..I figured i just copy the unxibench gzip to benchmark the vm.

But what i fail to understand is how do i copy the gzip tp vm while creating the vm ? I am using this script to create vms

```
 server = nova.servers.create(name = vmName, image = image.id, flavor = flavor.id,  nics = nics, availability_zone  = availability_zone , userdata = user_data, key_name = key_pair.name  )
```

Comment: check out cloud-init:  https://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/format.html

Comment: i did look into cloud-nit .. but could not understand these things :-   a) where do i put the gunzip package file? in my cloudinit script .. where and how to i specify to copy the gunzip file in a certian location and unzip and install it ..i wish cloud init had better documentation

Answer (score 0):

https://kimizhang.wordpress.com/2014/03/18/how-to-inject-filemetassh-keyroot-passworduserdataconfig-drive-to-a-vm-during-nova-boot/

file injection might work

> nova boot  –flavor 1 –image cirros  –nic
>   net-id=d58bbcac-1908-4cda-a9da-a13cfbbf4e77  –file
>   /fileinject=/root/keystonerc vm-file-inject